# Spearman's footrule distance with base R

Tags: r, vector, permutation, distance

Given two permutations:

```
v1
[1] 4 3 1 5 2

v2
[1] 2 3 4 5 1
```

How do you compute the Spearman's footrule distance (total displacement of all elements) with base R? (flexible for any two permutations of size `n`)

For example, for these two vectors, it's as follows:

`1` is moved `2` places from `v1` to `v2`
`2` is moved `4` places from `v1` to `v2`
`3` is moved `0` places from `v1` to `v2`
`4` is moved `2` places from `v1` to `v2`
`5` is moved `0` places from `v1` to `v2`

So the total distance would be: `2+4+0+2+0 = 8`

Comment: From the way you describe it, something like `abs(match(v1, v2) - seq_along(v1))` might be helpful. Could you add more (probably edge) cases for testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method using `sapply`, `which`, and `sum`:

```
sum(sapply(seq_along(v1), function(i) abs(i - (which(v2 == v1[i])))))
```

Here, we move along the indices of v1 and calculate the distance of the index of the element in the current index from its position in v2. These are then summed together.

I suspect something along the lines of @alexis_laz's solution in the comments may have greater computational efficiency.