# R: Calculating displacement of variables in order

Tags: r

We are developing an online test in which we present 6 images (in a row) that participants are asked to reshuffle from smallest to largest (the actual objective is more challenging, but besides the point here). The test begins with the images being presented in a random order. In the end, I would like to calculate the total displacement (or deviation) of the participant's response from the  correct response.

**To illustrate:**

We begin by presenting six images like so:

`[img1] [img2] [img3] [img4] [img5] [img6]`

A participant might then reshuffle the images to:

`[img2] [img4] [img3] [img1] [img6] [img5]`

The correct order for this trial might actually be:

`[img1] [img4] [img3] [img2] [img5] [img6]`

Thus, we see that the participant has not placed all images at the correct position: `img1` is displaced 3 positions to the left, while `img2` is displaced 3 positions to the right; and `img5` and `img6` are each displaced 1 position. Thus the total displacement is `3 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 8`

Is there an elegant way in R to calculate this displacement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spearman's footrule distance with base R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328325/spearmans-footrule-distance-with-base-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
sum(abs(match(x,y)-match(x,x)))
```

**Data**

```
x=c(2,4,3,1,6,5)
y=c(1,4,3,2,5,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am decomposing this a lot, obviously you can compress this on two lines if you want to.

This the correct output:

```
> correct_output <- data.frame(img=c(1, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6), rank=1:6)
  img rank
1   1    1
2   4    2
3   3    3
4   2    4
5   5    5
6   6    6
```

This is the user output:

```
> user_output <- data.frame(img=c(2, 4, 3, 1, 6, 5), user_rank=1:6)
  img user_rank
1   2         1
2   4         2
3   3         3
4   1         4
5   6         5
6   5         6
```

Let us bind them together:

```
> merge(correct_output, user_output, by="img")
  img rank user_rank
1   1    1         4
2   2    4         1
3   3    3         3
4   4    2         2
5   5    5         6
6   6    6         5
```

From here it is very easy. I am using the `dplyr` package.

```
> tmp <- mutate(tmp, penalty=abs(rank-user_rank))
  img rank user_rank penalty
1   1    1         4       3
2   2    4         1       3
3   3    3         3       0
4   4    2         2       0
5   5    5         6       1
6   6    6         5       1

> sum(tmp$penalty)
[1] 8
```